# Xamarin Android APK different name then in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, apk

In our Xamarin Android project, my collegue was playing around with the APK package name.
It should be something like: com.company.4productname.mobile
However, now it is: com.company.**x**4productname.mobile.

No were in the files, we can find this incorrect name. It seems like this name is not stored as text somewere.

Do you have any idea where this can be stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Android documentation, the packageName/applicationId has the following rules:

> And although the application ID looks like a traditional Java package
>   name, the naming rules for the application ID are a bit more
>   restrictive:
>
> - It must have at least two segments (one or more dots).
> - Each segment must start with a letter.
> - All characters must be alphanumeric or an underscore [a-zA-Z0-9_].

Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id

It appears that the Xamarin tooling is adding "x" in front of the "4" because starting with a number violates these rules.  I was also able to re-create this in Android Studio, and Android Studio does in fact generate an error because of the rules.  So it looks like Xamarin catches this error and then "fixes" it for you.

Comment: My bad.. I missed the thing that it cannot start with a number